# Is there a stack site for home automation / home security?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, security, automation

Perused the list, used search, and yet a home automation and/or home security site doesn’t seem to be available.  Seems like something a bunch of techie types would want to share info about. Is it really not here or did I just miss it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For now, [home automation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-automation) questions seem to be accepted on the Home Improvement site.  There are a few security questions there as well, but they don't seem to be very high-tech, so I can't say what kind of results you'll get.

There was a [Home Automation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20818/home-automation) proposal on Area 51.

Comment: Yep - home automation is OK on DIY - as long as you're doing it yourself :)

Comment: New URL for Area 51 site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55835/home-automation

Comment: The previous Area 51 proposal was discontinued and has been superceded by an Internet of Things (IoT) site proposal - show your support here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things

Comment: As per @Ghanima's answer, there is now a site for these questions.

Comment: @anonymous2 Maybe there is some tidy-up necessary to help steer questions to the right site? In trying to find the right place to ask, I've stumbled across questions to do with Z-Wave in Engineering, DIY, IoT and StackOverflow. Each site has some tags relating to home automation in one form or another.

Comment: @dsample, agreed.  The trouble, of course, is that IoT includes some questions that *are* on topic on SO, but might find better fits and a more supportive community on IoT.  I believe, however, that there is some effort to make some cross linking between IoT documentation on SO and the IoT stack, though I'm not 100% certain there. :)

Comment: @anonymous2 My problem wasn't really with SO (coding problems could easily be relevant/solvable there rather than IoT), but between DIY, Engineering and IoT it would be good to have some guidance in the tags that topics such as `home-automation` in DIY should really be `smart-home` in IoT, and `iot` in Engineering should probably be a more specific tag in IoT. It would be great if there was the ability to add tags from other sites to a question so I could harness the expertise of other communities.

Answer (score 22):

There is now the Stack Exchange site: [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/).

Its [help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) defines as on topic, questions about:

> - controlling, automating and sensing the environment using electronics ('smart devices'),
> - **consumer technology used for home automation,**
> - industrial applications of the Internet of Things, or
> - the security, privacy, reliability and safety of these devices

I would take it that home security insofar as it uses internetworked things (like sensor nodes) will fit this too.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: There's also https://arduino.stackexchange.com, which should probably just be merged with IoT.

Comment: @Saeb, I beg to differ. While there is some overlap (as is with many other stacks), there is much about Arduino that's not related to IoT and there's lots of IoT that is not Arduino-esque.

Comment: That's fair enough. I guess for my use cases I found a lot of overlap between the two sites and the fragmented information annoying. So if you're using Arduino for IoT, do you post on IoT or Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new Home Automation site under development in the Stack Overflow Area 51 section.
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55835/home-automation

To help make it a real site check out what needs to be done.  At this point people need to upvote questions to 10 points or more.  Help out if you want to make it real.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a couple of months ago, and whilst there's a proposal in Area 51 it doesn't seem to be going anywhere. The Home Improvement site doesn't really feel like the right place for home automation questions, as they get diluted to irrelevance by all the (legitimate) painting and decorating type questions.

The closest thing I have yet found is this:

http://hometechnologyintegration.org/questions

It's not as slick as a StackExchange site, but then what is (since they took it closed-source, anyway)?

Comment: Gavin - DIY home automation questions are OK. [**Installation, maintenance and repair** of major appliances.](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq) is mentioned in our FAQ and I think home automation can be classified as a major appliance.

Comment: Sure - but not all home automation is DIY, so the DIY site does not feel like a natural home; I think this is what the question actually pertains to. Though I could be wrong.

Comment: I see your point, and yes it would have to be about the DIY aspects. However I am speaking as a [moderator](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/194/chrisf) on the site.